# Substring a string in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to breakdown the string as searchText. The code is shown below:
`"asarrivalFDate=06/12/2017arrivalTDate=20/12/2017"` as

```
agentName= "as"
arrivalFDate= "06/12/2017" 
arrivalTDate="20/12/2017".
```

How can I achieve in C#. Here "as" can be any input entered by user.

I want to break and pass individual to Linq.

Comment: What have you tried? We´re not doing your work, you have to provide some own idea. In particular google for substring and you immediately find thousands of similar questions. Nevertheless it´s hard to get a general rule for your pattern based on one single example. What parts of your input are fixed, which ones are variable and in which way?

Comment: Ok I'll try once.

Comment: you are asking for a special case, is this case generalizable? meaning do you have other cases that are similar but a little bit different? or is this the only case of input? Is it always in the same format as you posted?

Comment: Your upate still doesn´t show any *data* entered by the user. What´s the format of the data? Are there allways two characters before `"arrivalFDate"`? Are your dates allways in DD/MM//YYYY-format? Honestly: you give us *one single input* and we should *guess* how to parse it?

Comment: The code you posted is irrelevant. We don't care how you are getting the string, we want to see what have you tried to do in order to parse it...

Comment: @HimBromBeere That can be any length string.

Comment: only characters? Numbers? Whitespaces also? Without this it´s **impossible** for us to know how your input is structured. Come on, please be more specific on your input. What if the agents name was  `"arrivalFDate"`? Btw.: why do you even parse your input-string yourself, when you allready use `Request.QueryString["searchText"]`? Doesn´t that do exactly what you want?

Comment: Is there a hat for deleting someones entire code exmaples?

Comment: @Saruman You could just roll-back the edit.

Comment: Thank you all for ur comments. I quit :(

Answer (score 1):

This code could help you:

```
string input = "asarrivalFDate=06/12/2017arrivalTDate=20/12/2017";
string wordToRemove1 = "arrivalFDate";
string wordToRemove2 = "arrivalTDate";

input = input.Remove(input.IndexOf(wordToRemove1), wordToRemove1.Length);
input = input.Remove(input.IndexOf(wordToRemove2), wordToRemove2.Length);

string[] inputSplitted = input.Split('=');

string agentName = inputSplitted[0];
string arrivalFDate = inputSplitted[1];
string arrivalTDate = inputSplitted[2];
```

I am removing the `arrivalFDate` and the `arrivalTDate` from your string, and then I split the remaining part of your string with `input.Split('=')`. Now you get a string array `string[] inputSplitted` that holds your desired values  (`agentName,arrivalFDate,arrivalTDate`) from the input string.

Answer (score 0):

Without using `RegEx` and just using `Split`

> Note : Assuming the format is always the same

**Code**

```
var input = "asarrivalFDate=06/12/2017arrivalTDate=20/12/2017";
var result = input.Split(
    new[]
        {
            "arrivalFDate=",
            "arrivalTDate="
        },
    StringSplitOptions.None);

string agentName = result[0];
string arrivalFDate = result[1];
string arrivalTDate = result[2];

Console.WriteLine(agentName);
Console.WriteLine(arrivalFDate);
Console.WriteLine(arrivalTDate);
```

**Output**

```
as
12/6/2017
12/20/2017
```